# Only allow ssh access from authorized_keys and nothing else?

Tags: ssh

I have a web server on my Raspberry Pi and I use ssh. Before I port forward I want to make sure it is very secure and hackers won't be able to do anything.

I have set up an ssh key from PuTTY on my computer so only my computer can access ssh without password.

I want to modify it so that anybody who tries to ssh into my server without having the authorised key will be refused.

Also, people with the authorised key can login but the have to enter the ssh password.

I am also going to install fail2ban later on.

Is this possible?

Suggestions and help are warmly welcomed...

Sid.

Comment: The only thing not covered in this series on SSH from our blog https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/150078167619/ssh-security-and-usability-part-6  is making those with authorised keys also use a password, which does not add much to the security of the system, as stolen keys should be revoked and each person should have their own key.

Comment: @SteveRobillard and the major thing missing from the blog is an index and a way for new users to actually find anything, or even know it exists. There is a lot of good stuff in there, but it is hidden under a rock, which is camouflaged. Even finding the linked Part 6 doesn't help you find Parts 1-5

Comment: @millways Most of what you say is true, but the first 5 parts are  linked right at the top of part 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable password authentication for SSH.

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

set:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

save file and restart

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```